# C# class null reference

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm using Ajax to bring back values from the server, but when calling the method `incrementvalue()`, `_value` has a null reference even though it is set up previously in the `intialisevalue()` method.  I have some example code below.

```
public class test
{
    public int value;

    public void increment(int _value)
    {
        value = value + _value;
    }

    public void setvalue(int _value)
    {
        value = _value;
    }
}

public test _value;

public JsonResult intialisevalue()
{
    _value = new test();
    _value.setvalue(9);

    return Json(_value);
}

public JsonResult incrementvalue()
{
    _value.increment(2);
    return Json(_value);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in summary, controllers are not stateful, therefore you cannot stored data in the controller between requests.

Answer (score 1):

controllers only exist within the request. after the response is sent the controller is disposed. thus, `test` no longer exists. you need to pass the test object into the controller

```
public JsonResult incrementvalue(test t, increment i)
{
      t.increment(i);
      return Json(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your value is not retained between calls to the controller. When you call the incrementvalue method, it's working with a new copy of that field. You'll probably find that it's throwing an exception because _value is null.

You should pass the copy of value into the incrementvalue method when you call the controller, then increment that and return it again.

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning a new reference to `_value` in the following method.

```
public JsonResult incrementvalue()
{
    _value.increment(2);
    return Json(_value);
}
```

you should modify it as follows.

```
public JsonResult incrementvalue()
{
    _value=new Test();   //Assigns a new reference to `_value`
    _value.increment(2);
    return Json(_value);
}
```

Comment: This would fix the error that might occur but you're only ever going to get 2 back when you call the incrementvalue method, and that doesn't sound like incrementvalue is doing it's job then.

Answer (score 0):

You need yo re-initialize _value each call to the server. HTTP is stateless, your variables do not keep their state between requests.